# Dialog when user hold a link

Tags: java, android, xml, hyperlink, webview

I have seen a lot of Android browsers which shows a dialog box when user holds a link or an image.

I am new to android and I have created a simple browser, and now I want to make this possible, so when user hold a link I have to show dialog like this

> http://the.url.com
>   *---------------------*
>  Open
>  Copy link address
>  Select Text

Any tutorial or a sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ContextMenu` for that purpose.

```
//Constants for context menu options
public static final int MENU_OPEN= 1;
public static final int MENU_COPY= 2;
public static final int MENU_SELECT= 3;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    ...
    ...
    // Especify that your veiw have a context menu attached
    registerForContextMenu(your view);
}
```

// here you create the conext menu

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, 
   ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_OPEN, Menu.NONE, "Open");
  menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_COPY, Menu.NONE, "Copy link address");
  menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SELECT, Menu.NONE, "Select Text");

}

// This is executed when the user select an option
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_OPEN:

        return true;
    case MENU_COPY:

        return true;
    case MENU_SELECT:

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```